# Javascript Array. Add first array to the first position that has a zero

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

How would I do the following as mentioned in the title.  I have looked online and I can push, slice etc to add the item but I want the first value to go to the first available position in the array that has a zero value;

For example:

```js
var arr = [4,1,2,7,10,0,0,0];
arr = arr.concat(arr.shift())

document.write(arr);
```

I want the output to be, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0;

So the first number in the array is sorted correctly, and replaced correctly and the last array is removed as the length should always remain the same - in this case eight;

Thanks.

Comment: Why does the expected output begin with a 0?

Comment: @Spectric `0` are probably empty spots.. Ok, no, I'm lost

Comment: "I can push, slice etc to add the item but I want the first value to go to the first available position in the array that has a zero value" do you expect to find a built in method to do it? Because your code doesn't follow this requirement at all.

Comment: `concat` adds two arrays together, `shift` _removes_ the first element from an array (it doesn't just get it, it removes it) and returns that as "not an array" but just as that value, so the code you're showing really doesn't do what you think you're trying to show. Also, _never_ use `document.write`, it does not do what you think it does, it's not part of modern JS, never ever use it. Use `console.log` if you want to see what's in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is somewhat cryptic but I'm sure the more you program and read on stackoverflow you get more decent in explaining what you want to achieve.

Maybe your problem can be broken down in a simple reduce function that sorts the array one single time.

**Aka add any number to our new array. If you find a 0 sort it - if you have not already.**

```js
const arr = [4,1,2,7,10,0,0,0];

const specialSortedArr = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc.push(curr);   
      // if there is not already a 0 in pole position lets sort the array we have!
      if (curr === 0 && acc[0] !== 0) {
        acc = acc.sort((a, b) => a - b);
       }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(specialSortedArr)
```